# How to connect an old front panel connector (audio) to a new motherboard?

Tags: audio, motherboard, connector, wiring, front-panel

The motherboard (Gigabyte Z170X-Gaming 7) has the following audio chip: *Audio: 5.1 (Creative Sound Core3D)*

**Frontpanel Audio Connector**

```
Return L
Return R
Ground
Ear L
Mic VCC
Ear R
Mic-In
```

**AC'97 Front Panel Audio** (not mentioned in the online manual)

```
1  = MIC
2  = GND
3  = MIC Power
4  = NC
5  = Line Out (R)
6  = NC
7  = NC
8  = No Pin
9  = Line Out (L)
10 = NC
```

Photo from the front panel audio connectors:

​[image: front panel audio connector]

If I get this right, this should be the correct match:

```
Ground  = GND
Mic VCC = MIC Power
Mic-In  = MIC
```

But what about the others? Is `Return L = Line Out (L)`?

Comment: I don't know if this is correct but perhaps it will be of help (disclaimer: try it at your own risk): http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/298273-30-connecting-front-panel-mobo

Comment: But what is headphone detection, mic detection? There is conflicting information on the internet ...

Comment: `Return L` and `Return R` look like Left and Right. This might be a [TRRS Connector](https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/) like you would find on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found out that the product website for the case is still online. Here all necessary information is described:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|               Ear & Mic connection                  |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| M/B layout (Ex: ASUS) |         Case layout         |
+---+-------------------+--------------------+--------+
| 1 | LINE_OUT R        | EAR R              | Red    |
| 2 | LINE_IN R         | Return R           | White  |
| 3 | LINE_OUT L        | EAR L              | Green  |
| 4 | LINE_IN L         | Return L           | Yellow |
| 5 | MIC               | MIC IN             | Red    |
| 6 | MIC PWR           | MIC VCC or MICBIAS | White  |
| 7 | Ground            | Ground             | Black  |
+---+-------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

To answer my question: `Return L/R` is `Line In L/R`. `Ear L/R` is `Line Out L/R` in my case. The result looks like this:

[image: correct connection]

But that was not enough. I had to install `Sound Blaster Pro Studio` (from the motherboard manufacturer driver page) and change some settings to get the front panel working:

- **Speakers/Headphones**: change the switch to headphones
- **Mixer**: beside the recording section there is a button called *Input devices*.  Change that to *microphone in the front*.